# xamarin form app file not saving on device storage

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have created xamarin form app for signpad which capture sign and saving png file to device storage but file is not writing on storage

here is my code to convert image to bytes[]

```
 var image = await signature.GetImageStreamAsync(SignaturePad.Forms.SignatureImageFormat.Png);//getting png file from here
        var signatureMemoryStream = image as MemoryStream;
        byte[] data = signatureMemoryStream.ToArray();// convert png to bytes[]
        string fileName = "img.png";
        DependencyService.Get<IFileReadWrite>().WriteData(fileName, data);
```

I have created DependencyService (Interface) for saving file

```
   public interface IFileReadWrite
   {
          void WriteData(string fileName, byte[] data);
   }
```

This is my code to save file using native(app.android) api

```
public class FileHelper : IFileReadWrite
{
    public void WriteData(string filename, byte[] data)
    {
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data); // this execute without error but file is not saving on path

    }
}
```

i already have given permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in mainfest

Comment: Replace this in your code and try: var documentsPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

Comment: Work like a charm.... Thank you so much @MShah

Comment: That's great,I'm adding this solution as an answer, please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this in your code and try:

`var documentsPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);`

Hope this may solve your issue.